# PopModalAsync pass data to parent

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Good evening everyone

Here I am trying for some time to mobile development with Xamarin.
I manage to create a list with data and I manage to open a Modal that contains fields that I fill with the data of the list. My problem is that I would like to retrieve the modal data (I have an input) to update the list. But I can not find how to pass my modal data to my list.
Below are the different elements that I use.

View of my list

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView x:Name="TableStock" RowHeight="40">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5,0,5,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ProductLabel}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding ProductUnit}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding InitialStock}" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Entry Grid.Column="0" x:Name="NewRealStock" Text="{Binding NewStock}" IsVisible="False" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

View of the controller from my list

```
public InputStock()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var listStock = Utils.Utils.GetStockByProduct();

        TableStock.ItemsSource = listStock;

        TableStock.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (TableStock.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if (TableStock.SelectedItem is RealStock item)
                {
                    var productName = item.ProductLabel;
                    var stockProduit = item.InitialStock;
                    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new RealStockModal(productName, productStock, item.CodeProduct));
                }
                TableStock.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        };
    }
```

View of my modal

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" x:Name="productName"/>
        <Entry x:Name="PrCode" IsVisible="False"/>
        <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" x:Name="newStock"/>
        <Entry HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" x:Name="realStock" Margin="25,0" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
        <Button Text="Enregistrer" VerticalOptions="End" Clicked="UpdateStock"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

What should I put in the controller of my modal to send the data in the list?
Thanks

Comment: You could use MessagingCenter.  You could raise an event in your modal.  You could simply pass an object to your modal and your page will have a reference to it when the modal dismisses.  You could pass a reference to the parent page when yo call the modal.

Comment: If you are using good MVVM practices, you should be able to update your item view model when you change the data, an then your item view model should be able to propagate those changes back to your main model, and then when you pop your modal page, the list page's view model can just refresh itself with the new data from the model. MVVM: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel

Comment: @jgoldberger-MSFT do you maybe have an example? Thanks

Comment: @deanwilliammills added and answer with source code

Answer (score 2):

deanwilliammills asked for an example, so here goes: (not using a database, only a model class to store the items, example is to show passing data from a modally presented item detail page back to the model view the view model).

This uses 2 way binding so that whenever the data is changed, the viewmodel is updated and the view model updates the model. So when the List page reloads, it already has the new data due to the bindings.

**Models:**

Person.cs:

```
using System;
namespace MVVMListAndDetailExample.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        static int nextId = 0;
        public Person()
        {
            Id = nextId++;
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }

    }
}
```

People.cs (singleton):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MVVMListAndDetailExample.Models
{
    public class People
    {
        private static readonly object padlock = new object();

        static People instance = null;
        public static People Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new People();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }


        private People()
        {
            PeopleList = new List<Person>();
            PeopleList.Add(new Person
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith",
                Age = 25,
                City = "New York City",
                State = "NY"
            });
            PeopleList.Add(new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Frank",
                LastName = "Lee",
                Age = 35,
                City = "San Francisco",
                State = "CA"
            });
            PeopleList.Add(new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Jessie",
                LastName = "Lane",
                Age = 45,
                City = "Chicago",
                State = "IL"
            });
            PeopleList.Add(new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Susan",
                LastName = "Jones",
                Age = 55,
                City = "Seattle",
                State = "WA"
            });
            PeopleList.Add(new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Greg",
                LastName = "Franklin",
                Age = 65,
                City = "Atlanta",
                State = "GA"
            });
            PeopleList.Add(new Person
            {
                FirstName = "Howard",
                LastName = "Waters",
                Age = 75,
                City = "Tampa",
                State = "FL"
            });

        }

        public List<Person> PeopleList { get; private set; }

    }
}
```

**View Models:**

BaseViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MVVMListAndDetailExample.ViewModels
{
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected BaseViewModel()
        {
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainPageViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace MVVMListAndDetailExample.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> peopleList = new ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> PeopleList
        {
            get { return peopleList; }
            set
            {
                if (peopleList != value)
                {
                    peopleList = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            foreach(Models.Person person in Models.People.Instance.PeopleList)
            {
                peopleList.Add(new PersonViewModel(person));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PersonViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MVVMListAndDetailExample.ViewModels
{
    public class PersonViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public PersonViewModel(Models.Person person)
        {
            this.person = person;
            firstName = person.FirstName;
            lastName = person.LastName;
            age = person.Age;
            city = person.City;
            state = person.State;
        }

        Models.Person person;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        int age;
        string city;
        string state; 

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return firstName; }
            set
            {
                if (firstName != value)
                {
                    firstName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();

                }
            }

        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return lastName; }
            set
            {
                if (lastName != value)
                {
                    lastName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

        }
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set
            {
                if (age != value)
                {
                    age = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

        }
        public string City
        {
            get { return city; }
            set
            {
                if (city != value)
                {
                    city = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

        }
        public string State
        {
            get { return state; }
            set
            {
                if (state != value)
                {
                    state = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            Models.People.Instance.PeopleList[Models.People.Instance.PeopleList.FindIndex(ind=>ind.Equals(person))] = person;
        }
    }
}
```

**Views:**

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage 
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design" 
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
   mc:Ignorable="d" 
   x:Class="MVVMListAndDetailExample.Views.MainPage"
   Title="Main Page"
   Padding="0,50,0,0">
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
               <StackLayout Padding="10,10,10,10">
                  <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding Age}" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding City}" />
                  <Label Text="{Binding State}" />
               </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MVVMListAndDetailExample.Views
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ViewModels.MainPageViewModel();
        }

        async void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Views.PersonDetailPage(e.Item as ViewModels.PersonViewModel));
        }
    }
}
```

PersonDetailPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
   xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   x:Class="MVVMListAndDetailExample.Views.PersonDetailPage"
   Title="Person Detail Page"
   Padding="0,50,0,0">
   <ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout>
         <Entry Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <Entry Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <Entry Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <Entry Text="{Binding City, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <Entry Text="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <Button Text="Save" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" />
      </StackLayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

PersonDetailPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MVVMListAndDetailExample.Views
{
    public partial class PersonDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public PersonDetailPage(ViewModels.PersonViewModel personViewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = personViewModel;
        }

        async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Full source code here: https://github.com/jgold6/XamarinSupportSamples/tree/master/MVVMListAndDetailExample

Answer (score 1):

A good way is to use an Action and pass that through the constructor of the modal page.  Something like ...

```
Public class ItemPage(Action<Someclass> callback)
```

That action and it’s definition is defined within the listview page context.

Then when you want to go back from the modal page to the list, invoke the action passing whatever set of data you want to get back to the list and from that action, pop the modal page.

This means you’re popping the modal page from the list page context, not the modal page itself.